# Advanced Breadcrumbs disabled my drop down menu

Tags: jquery, joomla, module

My knowledge of jQuery is limited, but I believe I'm experiencing a jQuery conflict. I'm using the Mega Menu as my navigation menu at the top of the page and the problem I'm having is that my drop down menu isn't "dropping down" on certain pages. I've installed some extensions that claim to help with jQuery conflicts, but I can't seem to get them to work, so those are disabled at this point.

If you visit this page, you'll notice that nothing drops down on the top menu (all you'll see is a small triangle when you hover over the menu).

http://gator626.hostgator.com/~tyriggs/gantrytest/index.php/terri-austin

However, if you visit the Press Releases or Committees section everything on the top menu works fine.

The problem seems to stem from the Advanced Breadcrumbs Module not getting along with Mega Menu. I tried adjusting the z-index, but I think it's something deeper than that.

If it's a jQueryNoConflict issue, where do I put that snippet of code?

This is a page without the Advanced Breadcrumbs Module enabled and the menu works seamlessly: http://gator626.hostgator.com/~tyriggs/gantrytest/index.php/john-bartlett

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Stop guessing. Open the console of your browser (F12 usually) and see if there are any errors and paste them here